# FBX export screws up textures?

Tags: texturing, export

Not really sure what's going on here.

Exporting this mesh as an FBX, then re-importing to Blender, completely screws it up. A bunch of sections are see-through -- it seems like the normals, but the only fix I've found is creating an entirely new texture. Appending the same mesh works just fine (comparison below). Tested FBX export + re-import on other meshes and they work just fine.

The yellow bits without a texture seem unaffected.

Is there any easy fix to this? I can work around it, but it's incredibly annoying.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Eevee? that's the default when you open Blender so I'll assume so as you're reimporting your FBX

From my own experience working with FBX files, what might be going on here is that the texture opacity settings may not be being properly preserved in the FBX file.

On each material used in the object, ensure your Blend Mode in the Settings Tab is set correctly:

[image]

I find Alpha Clip or Alpha Blend works best. Anyway, you possibly had this set right in the first place but the FBX export/import didn't carry this over.

You may also need to go into each of your material nodes and reconnect any alpha masks/maps/textures as appropriate.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to solve it. I discovered that for whatever reason the FBX keeps changing Blend Mode to Alpha Blend on import or export. After importing, going into each material setting and changing back to "opaque" fixes the appearance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like EEVEE material blend mode should be set to something other than "blend"

I've made an addon that helps fix this quickly if you need to change multiple materials https://blendermarket.com/products/super-importer-